# How to output MSTest exception message

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have an MSTest and want to output an exception without using `try` and `catch`; how can I output the exception message within `TestCleanup`?

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        double expected = 9.0;
        double actual = 8.0;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Exception e;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception message do you want to output? You should be able to see the assertion error message in the test runner UI (e.g. Test explorer)

Comment: Yes, I can see error message in test runner and I want grab that same massage and output on my report.

Comment: if throwing an exception is what it's supposed to do, you could look into the [ExpectedExceptionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx). If not, @YacoubMassad is right, the test runner should cover it; why not go for try-catch?